# What is up with all these OGL questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

They seem highly subjective and reiterative but frankly I don't have enough evidence to say one way or another. But I do think they need to be cleaned up.

Comment: @anon186: This question was probably useful at the time, but appears to have become cruft (not clear what it's about, no useful conclusions can be drawn). Consider deletion?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one that's written neutrally, and that's [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2208/what-can-make-ogl-material-harder-or-easier-to-reuse-in-other-products). I wish we'd given [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/what-are-the-top-ten-examples-of-ogl-content-that-is-the-easiest-and-most-well-fo) a bit longer -- Netherwerks might have been willing to revise his question, and I think it'd be fair to give him a chance to do so.

Aramis' answer is excellent either way.

Comment: Thanks, Bryant!