# How long should people have to revise their questions?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

Bryant made an interesting comment on [What is up with all these OGL questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/what-is-up-with-all-these-ogl-questions):

> I wish we'd given this one a bit
>   longer -- Netherwerks might have been
>   willing to revise his question, and I
>   think it'd be fair to give him a
>   chance to do so.

What is a fair length of time to allow people to revise a possibly good question before we close it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I don't think we should wait at all, since [they can fix the question once it's closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/edit-a-closed-question/291#291).  If you leave a bad question open, it will usually draw more answers and views than it deserves.

Comment: Not a bad point. I'd be more comfortable with cutting it shorter after we have moderators, since at that point it'll be relatively easy for a fixed question to be re-opened.

Comment: +1: A close still lets the OP edit it, and if it's improved, it can be reopened.

Comment: @Bryant It'll be nice for closing to.  Right now we only have 11 or so users who can even cast a vote.

Answer (score 1):

My personal guideline is 24 hours, but that's just a gut feeling.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it takes to get 5 people to vote to close it. The faster the better.

If you want to reopen your question, edit it and then bring the matter up on meta.