# Should the moderators delete obsolete questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

This question probably mostly applies to meta, although it might be relevant to the main site.

The question prompting this question can be found [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/what-is-up-with-all-these-ogl-questions). No doubt it was perfectly sensible at the time, but the phenomenon it alludes to has gone, and there is only one answer (looks as though others were deleted) that is also useless without context, and contains broken links.

I've already tagged the question for mod attention (or tried to) without result. Is the policy just to leave this sort of thing lying around? I would have thought cleaning up as we go was a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually we leave things about unless they are patently offensive, or otherwise problematic.  This is definitely more true for the primary site for meta.  As far as the question in question (*?*) I haven't decided it's enough of a problem to go.  One of the other mods can feel free to delete it, once they've worked off their turkey.

Comment: @C. Ross Ah yes! Happy Thanksgiving from across the pond! I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if there are other opinions out there. I think I'll also edit the title to "Should..." as this probably captures my concern better.

Comment: I have to agree - I prefer to let the community work.  I don't want to be in the role of determining what's obsolete or not and trying to somehow conduct polls on it.  I'd rather people of sufficient rep vote to delete and there we go. I don't see a reason for that question to be around, but maybe someone does.  If only as a warning to not post goofy limited-time questions even on meta.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. Not that many non-mods have the rep to delete questions right now. If I had the rep I would certainly vote to delete, but I don't. I don't really understand what makes you want to leave this sort of cruft in place once you've seen it, but I guess it's not a huge problem either. Oh well...

Comment: @mxyzplk: Not to seem argumentative here, only curious, but who are these people with "sufficient rep" to delete questions? Is it those with rep 2000 and hence access to mod tools? Are these people not de facto moderators?? I don't see the privilege listed anywhere else.

Comment: @Dave Yes, it's the `moderator tools` users.  It takes 3 votes to delete a 0 votes closed question.  If you want to set a question up to be deleted, close it.

Comment: @C. Ross: Thanks, most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Context of "Obsolete" is pretty much impossible to define for the main board... some of the games people have asked about date back 30 years+!

Even many of the "duplicates" are sufficiently reworded that leaving them in place with an answer nicely pointing to the other wording's answer list is often going to be of benefit..

Comment: Yes, I agree. I did say "probably mostly applies to meta", and as yet I haven't been able to imagine a parallel question that would be relevant on the main site and then become irrelevant. Probably because there won't be one!